# What is the name for class used to store row from result set?

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm, naming-conventions

For performance reason many report queries performed outside of ORM managed objects.

For storing results I use one-per-query class to hold row of data between DB access method and services.

For example in Java/Hibernate/Spring:

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<DataDAO, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.evil.db.XXX(...) from #{#entityName} where ...")
    List<XXX> findXXX(...);
```

What is the name for `XXX`? Is it [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) or [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) or [Business object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object)? How intermediate storage class is named in pattern books and framework reference manuals? It's a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) but this term too generic...

I usually hold this classes as inner static classes and have no issue to give names appropriate to containing data.

But I like to add suffix for class name if it top level class to represent its role, like traditionally it is done for `DAO`/`Service`/`Controller`/etc...

Comment: IMO objects loaded from the database don't need any additional suffix. For example, there is nothing wrong with calling the classes `User`, `Location`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the *Repository Pattern*, you shouldn't have this naming problem. The repository pattern usually gets oriented by interface  named *IRepository* - or can also be an abstract class - that represents generic operations on the database, as follows (C# Code):

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
}
```

In your case, as you need some custom queries, you shall create a interface for your specific cases. The following example refers to a specific repository for the product domain (*IProductRepository*) that force implementation for *IRepository*.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
    Product GetProductBySomething(string somemething);
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAvailableProducts();
}
```

And finally, you'll create a concrete class that implements the *IRepositoryProduct*.

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public void Add(Product entity)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Delete(Product entity)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Get(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAvailableProducts()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Product GetProductBySomething(string somemething)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Update(Product entity)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Update(Product entity)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

With this approach you shouldn't have naming problems for your methods, 'cause they will follow the interface convention.

Comment: Unfortunately you miss my question... I query for data that have different signature then any ORM managed Entity and don't know name for classes that represent this data... Look at `select new com.evil.db.XXX(...) ...` syntax above...

Comment: @gavenkoa, now I've got it! It's commonly denominated "Model".